# Rump unikernel nginx logs

Tags: nginx, unikernel

I just run the [rump tutorial](https://github.com/rumpkernel/wiki/wiki/Tutorial%3A-Serve-a-static-website-as-a-Unikernel) to create a [unikernel for nginx](https://github.com/manageacloud/rumprun-packages/tree/master/nginx) to deliver static content.

The tutorial works perfectly, but I have a questions about logging. The unikernel is sending all the [error logs to `stderr`](https://github.com/manageacloud/rumprun-packages/blob/master/nginx/images/data/conf/nginx.conf#L2) (and therefore is captured by the `qemu` output terminal) but the [access logs are sent to /dev/null](https://github.com/manageacloud/rumprun-packages/blob/master/nginx/images/data/conf/nginx.conf#L18).

How can I capture the nginx access_log in for this case ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question. According to the [Wiki](https://github.com/rumpkernel/wiki/wiki/Repo%3A-rumprun#logging) logging is currently available using remote syslog.